# .htaccess show 404 error if url has extra slashes

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

This is my URL structure

```
http://example.com/filename-.html
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^filename-([0-9]+)\.html$ filename.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

issue is that if there is a wrong url it doesn't go to 404 error page

Example wrong urls

http:///example.com/filename-18-bank/////-4.html

http://example.com//////listing-560.html

How can i tell .htaccess to redirect these url to 404 error document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can **insert this rule just below `RewriteBase` line**:

```
# send any request containing multiple / to 404
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} //
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]
```